# App blows up due to calling PFUser enableAutomaticUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I need to restrict user data so that nobody, other than the app user, can read his / her data. Looking at the docs I thought that putting these two lines:

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:[PFACL ACL] withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` would do it. But when there is no current user and it's a new installation, the app crushes on

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Between the `enableAutomaticUser` and the `makeKeyAndVisible` all I'm doing is loading static data and initializing `UIViewController`s - with the user object untouched.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, lets start with the crash. What does the console say when the app crashes?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values

Comment: Well that does tell you exactly why it crashed. You're using a nil value on the PFObject.

Comment: OK but which one? Why does it only happen once I call [PFUser enableAutomaticUser]?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is that once I called `[PFUser enableAutomaticUser]` there is a user in the system, so a check of

```
if([PFUser currentUser])
```

returns `TRUE`. But the `objectId` does not exist until the user is saved to the datastore.

So when I attempted to add the `[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]` the system crushed.